# is this possible to hook on messages that child process is sending to windows console?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, hook

As of now I tried `SetWindowsHookEx`, but it seems that it isn't able to catch messages from console window.

Code illustrating this :

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

HHOOK hHook = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK Callback(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) { 
  cout << "tick: " << GetTickCount() << ", code: " << code << ", wParam: "
    << wParam << ", lParam: " << lParam << endl;
  return CallNextHookEx(hHook,code,wParam,lParam);
}

int main() {

  int idHook[14] = { WH_CALLWNDPROC, WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, WH_CBT, WH_DEBUG,
    WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE, WH_GETMESSAGE, WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK, WH_JOURNALRECORD,
    WH_KEYBOARD, WH_KEYBOARD_LL, WH_MOUSE, WH_MOUSE_LL, WH_SHELL,
    WH_SYSMSGFILTER };

  for (int i=0 ; i<=14 ; i++) {
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx( idHook[i] , (HOOKPROC)Callback,
      NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
  }

  system("dir");
  //here appeared nothing insead `dir` output, but why ?
  system("pause");
  MessageBox(NULL, "Now creating window ...", "... and messages appear.", 0);
}
```

Another way that I looked at is api of the console itself, specifically the `ReadConsoleInput()` function. But it is not working through callback so it is only useable for catching key or mouse events. Example code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But what I need is to take hold of console calls that are issued by process that was created through `system` or `CreateProcess`. By calls I mean for example to catch every `printf()` issued by child process before it gets to the console that my process owns.

Any chance is that possible ?

Comment: How is this different to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171785/it-is-possible-to-put-a-hook-catching-messages-that-are-send-to-console-by-child) posted less than 24 hours ago?

Comment: I thought that if I provide proof that I have spend some time on the problem and show that I tried some possibilities before asking, I finally get an honest answer. (Answer (before yours) to previous question was wrong.) - And I still wait for someone who maybe knows a way, maybe is there some undocumented possibility.

Comment: Then you should be updating the existing question and comment on the incorrect answers as appropriate. Creating new questions just makes a mess and decreases the signal to noise ratio of the site.

Comment: Who would see my question then ? Do edited questions jump to top ?

Comment: No, but if it's [written properly and tagged correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) then people will see it. If they can answer, they will. If you want to increase exposure after a few days, you can start a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty). This site is NOT a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try output redirection. Create two pipe objects (one for stdout and another for stderr) using `CreatePipe` API, and pass them in `hStdOutput` and `hStdError` members of `STARTUPINFO` when invoking `CreateProcess`. Anything the child process outputs will not be displayed, but will go through these pipes; you can then filter the data as appropriate and output it yourself.

Comment: yes, I know this way, but some programs attached to pipes behave differently, I need to do it because windows console quits when something tries send to it utf-8 data, I thought of capturing this and using `WriteConsoleW` to bypass the problem

Comment: @rsk82 Are you saying that some hypothetical program might not work right when you redirect pipes? That's unreasonable. You would rather use some extremely ugly hack/undocumented-stuff to do it just in case of a badly made program? You said you were processing the output. Seems you know exactly what program it is.